# Remove a Backbone View from the Router

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

How can I remove a backbone view from my router?  I'm trying to run a check that says, if a certain view exists remove it.  I just can't figure out the syntax to make this happen.

I have tried:

```
if(typeof mysite.city != "undefined")
 {
  console.log(mysite.city.View.prototype.__proto__.remove);

  //Calling this remove function throws the error
  mysite.city.View.prototype.__proto__.remove();
 }
```

but I get some uncaught exception error that I can't fully read since a page reload is forced. My console.log outputs: function (){this.$el.remove();return this} I just don't know how to get that to execute.

Comment: Can't you catch it and `window.alert()` it, to avoid the page reload?

Comment: No, that actually didn't work either, but the message is:

Type Error: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined.

I was able to read it after refreshing several times.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly call `mysite.city.remove()`? I suppose you cannot do that for some strange reason (such as: you did override the `remove` function and lost the original functionality; if that's the case, why did you override the method, if you now need to call it?). If you *must* call the original `remove` method from Backbone's `View`, you could try this:

```
View.prototype.remove.call(mysite.city);
```

That will set the context of the `remove` function to the object `mysite.city`. Otherwise, when executing the `remove` function the way you called it, `this` will be undefined.